# Load Default Selected Option from Database

Tags: html, mysql

I have a page where users select an option from a form to update their profile information. Right now I'm using "selected" in the option tag to determine the default selected option. For example:

```
<select name="age">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option selected value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

I've tried for a while and I can't figure out how to make it so that the option that they have chosen(which is stored in the database) can be the default option when they view that "update profile" page.

For extra clarity, if I update my profile and choose age "2", when I refresh that page I'd like for "2" to become the default selection.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:

I can properly retrieve the age currently in the database using:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users1 WHERE username = '" .      $_GET["username"] . "'

");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo '</td></tr><tr><td><font color="#FFFFFF"> Age: </td> </font> <td> '.$row['age'];
```

I just can't think of how to use this somehow with the select tag

Comment: What are you using on the server-side ? PHP ? Are you serving .HTML files or are the files generated dynamicaly ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm a noob so I'll explain what I understand. Right now this form sends the info to a php file which uses sql to update the database, based on who is logged in. I used 'PHP Admin' in my hostgator cPanel to create the database. I hope that answered your question... If not I'm sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to use to get the value from the database?  I used to do this with PHP by generating the select options.  The logic below should help to get you started.  If your select options are in HTML, you may want to look at Ajax/jQuery to retrieve the values from the database and update the HTML form accordingly.

```
for item in array {
     (item = "user selected value from database") ? <option value=item selected=selected>item</option> : <option value=item>item</option>
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the code that retrieves the age correctly. Thanks!